# SQL Server report's saved URL as bookmark not working

Tags: url, reporting-services

I have report deployed on a SQL Server Reporting server. It has one multivalue parameter called 'Names' as a input for stored procedure which fetch data to display the result. In URL, I am adding all values selected for multivalue parameter are concatenating with '&' character.

I need to store this URL for further uses as a bookmark in my browser which is also working fine. Problem occurs when over a time one of the values for that parameter gets missing from the database then report comes blank.

Some points I would like to clear here:

- Stored procedure is working fine even if some values are missing.
- I could figure out that this might be because of that value is not present in the dropdown of 'Names' so it is unable to assign it before running the stored procedure. As a solution to this problem I tried to hide this parameter from report by clearing prompt box for 'Names', but I now get

  > The ''Names'' parameter is missing a value

Comment: One correction, Values for names are separated by '&namesvalue' not by just '&'

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the report (`.rdl`) into reporting server, make sure "Name" parameter has a default value, this way the stored procedure is able to get the default value even if the link is missing the "Name" parameter

Comment: Thanks for your reply Freddy. This issue was because of parameter value was missing from available values of dropdown "Name" parameter. I figured out one solution, I have created one hidden parameter which takes value fro URL and verifies it wth database and then populates dropdown. This solution worked for me.

Comment: I am facing different issue now. I am unable to clear the value from that hidden variable. I have searched a lot but couldn't figure it out. My problem is similar to this one [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234761/set-parameter-back-to-default-value-in-ssrs  Has anyone found the solution for this one?

Comment: Ok, you should vote if the answers could be useful for someone else, let me try to help you  with the new issue, I guess you should create a new question

Comment: I think I got it, yoy are able to create some query to set the drod down with variables, this way is not necessary create hidden fields

Comment: Query is already there to populate dropdown and hidden variable was necessary to verify values coming through URL with the DB because of values don't exist in DB then report will just come blank. Now I just need a way to clear or change one report parameter's value based on some condition of another report parameter's value.